# Xcode debugger doesn't display any code

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I'm a C++ noob, have been using Terminal/gcc to compile and run my code, but wanted to make the switch to Xcode (v 3.2.5). I've been going through some tutorials but having problems getting the Debugger to work properly.

When I select Build and Debug, if my code has no errors, the Debugger and Debugger Console open and I get a message in the console that debugging ended normally.

When there are errors in the code, I get red  error icons in the Editor, but neither the Debugger nor the console open automatically. This isn't a big deal, I can manually open the Debugger. What is a problem is that when I do open it, it's completely empty: nothing at all in the threads, vars or editor panes.

I'm using the default build configuration for the template Command Line Tool > C++ stdc++ (Generate Debug Symbols: on, Strip Debug Symbols: off, Optimization: off). I read the "Troubleshooting Debugger Display" section in the Xcode Debugging Guide and it seems like I'm doing all those things correctly, but as I said, I'm a beginner, so maybe I'm overlooking something really obvious? Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You need to set at least one **breakpoint** in your code, otherwise it will just run to completion (assuming there are no runtime errors).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your statement about red error icons in the editor, it sounds like you have compile-time errors in your program.

I think you might be confused about what a debugger is for - it's used to find *runtime* errors with your code, not compile-time errors. The debugger won't be any use to you if your code isn't syntactically correct.

Comment: Thanks, Carl, for the clarification. I was just randomly commenting out lines of code to intentionally generate errors for the purposes of the tutorial I was following (i.e., to explore the Debugger), so I'll try making some changes that still allow the code to compile but generate runtime errors. Thanks again.